# Mini-game. Ruby the hard way exercise 35

Tags: ruby, control-structure

I'm currently learning ruby from the [Learn Ruby the hard way tutorial.](http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex35.html) And in that exercise, the author ask us to add things to a simple game. However, I was trying this to improve the **bear_room method** by doing something like this:

```
while true
print "> "
choice = gets.chomp.downcase!
if choice.include? ("taunt")
  dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
elsif choice.include? "taunt" && !bear_moved
  puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
  bear_moved = true
elsif choice.include? "taunt" && bear_moved
  dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
elsif choice.include? "open" && bear_moved
```

However, when I write this:

```
choice = gets.chomp.downcase!
```

It gives me this error when executing:

```
ex35.rb:44:in `bear_room': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from ex35.rb:99:in `start'
from ex35.rb:109:in `<main>'
```

But if do something like this:

```
choice = gets.chomp.downcase
```

or this:

```
choice = gets.chomp
choice.downcase!
```

It works. **Why is that?** I would appreciate any kind of help. Also, **how works the `while true` bit?** That really gets me confused.

Here is the rest of the program in case that you need it. I'm going to leave "separated" the mentioned method to make it easier to read.

```
# Creates the 'gold_room' method, so it can be called later.
def gold_room
  puts "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

  print "> "
  choice = gets.chomp
  # Converts the 'choice' variable to integer type.
  choice.to_i

  # Checks if 'choice' is equals to 0, OR greater or equal to 1.
  if choice == '0' || choice >= '1'
  # Saves the integer 'choice' variable in the 'how_much' variable.
    how_much = choice.to_i
  else
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
  end

  # Checks if the 'how_much' variable is lesser than 50, and executes the code below if so.
  if how_much < 50
    puts "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
    exit(0)
  elsif how_much >= 50 && how_much < 100
    puts "Mmm, ok that's enough. Get out!"
  else
    dead("You greedy bastard!")
  end
end


################### bear_room method ###################


# Creates the 'bear_room' method.
def bear_room
puts "There is a bear here."
puts "The bear has a bunch of honey."
puts "The fat bear is in front of another door."
puts "How are you going to move the bear?"
puts "1. Taunt the bear."
puts "2. Steal the bear's honey. "

# Declares the 'bear_moved' variable as a boolean, initialize it to false.
   bear_moved = false

  while true
    print "> "
    choice = gets.chomp.downcase
    if choice.include? ("taunt")
      dead("The bear looks at you then slaps your face off.")
    elsif choice.include? "taunt" && !bear_moved
      puts "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
      bear_moved = true
    elsif choice.include? "taunt" && bear_moved
      dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elsif choice.include? "open" && bear_moved
      gold_room
    else
      puts "I got no idea what that means."
    end
  end
end

############### end of method ###############





# Defines the 'cthulhu_room' method.
def cthulhu_room
  puts "Here you see the great evil Cthulhu."
  puts "He, it, whatever stares at you and you go insane."
  puts "Do you flee for your life or eat your head?"

  print "> "
  choice = gets.chomp

  # Checks if the user's input contains the word 'flee'. If so, executes the code below.
  if choice.include? "flee"
    start
  # Checks if the user's input contains the word 'head'. If so, executes the code below instead.
  elsif choice.include? "head"
    dead("Well that was tasty!")
  else
    # Otherwise, calls the 'cthulhu_room' method again.
    cthulhu_room
  end
end

# Defines the 'dead' method. It takes one argument (why). Example: dead("Well that was tasty!")
def dead(why)
  puts why, "Nice."
  # Succesfully finish the program.
  exit(0)
end

# Defines the 'start' method, wich is where the game begins. Duh.
def start
  puts "You are in a dark room."
  puts "There is a door to your right and left."
  puts "Which one do you take?"

  print "> "
  choice = gets.chomp

  # Start the branching. It checks the user's input, and saves that on the 'choice' variable, which is used along the whole program in the other methods.
  if choice == "left"
    # Calls the 'bear_room' method.
    bear_room
  elsif choice == "right"
    # Calls the 'cthulhu_room' method.
    cthulhu_room
  else
    dead("You stumble around the room until you starve.")
  end
end

# Start the game.
start
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

**TL;DR:** What's the difference between `choice = gets.chomp.downcase!` and

```
choice = gets.chomp
choice.downcase!
```

---

**PS:** The comments are part of the exercise. Please, if you have any type of correction (about the comments, how I made the question, code in general, etc) **please** tell me so I can improve. Thanks and sorry for the length!

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because if the string did not change upon calling `downcase!` it returns `nil`. Thus when you try and call `include?` it says that `nil` does not have such a method.

Thus, it is safest to use the "non-destructive" version of `downcase`. The `downcase!` method mutates the string in place if it can.

Check the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase-21) for further reading.

Comment: But if the `downcase!` change the object that it's applied to, why `gets.chomp.downcase!` doesn't work?

Comment: @LeonardoGuédez It is because you are assigning it to a value. Like you specified, if you call `choice.downcase!` separately you don't assign the value to anything and instead `choice` is changed implicitly.